# Объясните критерии ТЗ

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Пишу ТЗ. Небольшая иерархия классов с реализацией основных принципов ООП. Вот мой проект

[image: дерево проекта]

(есть абстрактный класс electric_app.., классы наследники в пакете equipments и main с menu)

Есть определённые критерии к проекту, которые я не понимаю, а именно:

4.Проверка работоспособности через тесты.
(Какие тесты? Как их провести и где почитать)

5.Для хранения параметров инициализации можно использовать файлы.
(В частности просили изучить MySql, с этим кое-как, думаю, разберусь, ладно)

6.Использовать механизм логгирования.
(Тут полный ноль, читал, что есть несколько фичей на этот счёт, может кто порекомендовать что? (Почитать хотя бы))

7.Использовать библиотеки сборки.
(??? Имеется ввиду задействовать библеотеки java или чьи-то другие или что?)

8.Неформально предложили сделать какой-то GUI, но я вообще тут не шарю. В универе только консольные приложения на c++ и c# писал.
Читал про swing, но говорят, что он устарел и тот же javafx гораздо "богаче".
javafx? хмм, что-то пытался, но как-то находил только ссылки, где показывали как кнопку одну добавить. Да и после android studio и windows forms(.net) вручную всё описывать слегка непривычно. Может кто-что посоветовать?

Comment: Для Fx нет необходимости описывать все вручную, есть SceneBuilder. Если решите в это ввязаться, не берите версию java выше 8, если не хотите дополнительно изучать модульность.

Comment: одно из условий - использование java выше 8ой версии, увы)

Comment: ну тогда страницы две вопросов по метке javafx как раз про запуск на 11 версии в помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

далее идет 100% IMHO

> 4.Проверка работоспособности через тесты. (Какие тесты? Как их провести и где почитать)

Имеются ввиду unit-тесты, это такие маленькие программы, которые всячески используют ваш код и проверяют результаты на корректность. Для этого существуют специальные библиотеки ([junit](https://habr.com/ru/post/120101/), [mockito](https://habr.com/ru/post/243155/)). Необходимость юнит-тестов, даже если для вас пока она для вас туманна, очень большая. Они по факту являются **контрактом** к вашему коду, и помогают понять что-вы что-то сломали, если их постоянно прогонять перед компиляцией.
Писать код, который легко покрыть тестами весьма непросто, и по началу вам не будет хотеться их писать.

> 6.Использовать механизм логгирования. (Тут полный ноль, читал, что есть несколько фичей на этот счёт, может кто порекомендовать что?
>   (Почитать хотя бы))

**Логгирование** - это запись информации о работе приложения в постоянное хранилище(файл, база данных, облако, /dev/null).
Вы можете это делать и руками, но для этого существует множество решений. [немного истории](https://habr.com/ru/post/113145/) и [сравнение логгеров](https://habr.com/ru/post/247647/).

> 7.Использовать библиотеки сборки. (??? Имеется ввиду задействовать библеотеки java или чьи-то другие или что?)

Это такие специальные средства, которые автоматизируют рутинную работу программиста, вроде менеджмента зависимостей и запуска компилятора с необходимыми условиями, unit-тестов итд. С ними от написания кода, до получения готового приложения для поставки нужна одна команда и все. [статья про maven на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/309222/) [статья про gradle на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/107085/)

> 8.Неформально предложили сделать какой-то GUI, но я вообще тут не шарю. В универе только консольные приложения на c++ и c# писал. Читал
>   про swing, но говорят, что он устарел и тот же javafx гораздо
>   "богаче". javafx? хмм, что-то пытался, но как-то находил только
>   ссылки, где показывали как кнопку одну добавить. Да и после android
>   studio и windows forms(.net) вручную всё описывать слегка непривычно.
>   Может кто-что посоветовать?

Swing устарел, но не сломался, на нем по прежнему можно написать gui, по нему много туториалов в интернете и ответов на этом ресурсе. Для учебного задания он отлично подойдет, хоть он и не торт.

JavaFX - новая штука, но попробовать её в реальном деле, в отличие от swing, мне не довелось. Только один компонент - WebView. С ним все прекрасно - показывает веб странички.

Графика это отдельная очень обширная тема, рисовать можно и при помощи видеокарты, но на данной стадии это только все усложнит.